# Listview struck when scrollong?

Tags: android, listview

I am using to listview to show images but it struck when scrolling i dnt know why i have also used Lazyloading , I have also showing text only without images then it is also strucking please tell me what is the problem ?

Tis is my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wallshadow"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_ImageSlider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/movingheader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            >

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Question is loading...."
            android:textColor="#2b2b2b"
            android:textSize="@dimen/questiontextsize"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

              <RelativeLayout
                  android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:background="#D4AF37" > 
            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>





        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/movingheader"
            android:id="@+id/layoutImageContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/wallViewPagerParent"
              >

          <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
              android:id="@+id/pager"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/wallSliderParent"
              android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
              android:background="@drawable/full_img"
              android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_userImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_pic_frame" />


            <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/pager"

                android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_userImage"
                >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textVew_WallUserName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"


                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#2b2b2b"
                android:textSize="@dimen/nametextsize"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_PostDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textVew_WallUserName"

                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"

                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#D6D6D6"
                android:textSize="@dimen/datetextsize"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layoutImageContainer"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/commentsandokayborder"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textVew_WallTotalokayTEXT"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ok_icon" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textVew_WallTotalComments"
                android:src="@drawable/comments_iocn" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textVew_WallTotalComments"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#D4AF37"
                android:textSize="@dimen/commenttextGoldensize"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textVew_WallTotalokay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#D4AF37"
                android:textSize="@dimen/okaytextGoldensize"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textVew_WallTotalokayTEXT"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textVew_WallTotalokay"
                android:text=" "
                android:textColor="#2b2b2b"
                android:textSize="@dimen/okaytextsize" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <!-- textVew_WallTotalokay -->
</RelativeLayout>





public class WallLatestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //Variables

    Activity activity;
    private List<okayWallProps> data;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    protected boolean isScrolling=false;
    mageLoaderWallUserImage imageLoader;
    private static int[] pagePositon;
    public WallLatestAdapter(Activity act, List<okayWallProps> wallData, ListView lst){


        pagePositon = new int[10000];

        activity=act;
        data=wallData;
        mInflater=  (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                /*LayoutInflater.from(act);*/
        imageLoader=new mageLoaderWallUserImage(act);

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        viewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_walllayout, parent,false);
            holder=new viewHolder();

            holder.questionName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.questionName.setTypeface(fontsFamily.getFont(activity, true));

            holder.commentDount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textVew_WallTotalComments);

            holder.okayCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textVew_WallTotalokay);

            holder.userImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_userImage);

            holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_PostDate);
            holder.date.setTypeface(fontsFamily.getNameFont(activity));

            holder.userName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textVew_WallUserName);
            holder.userName.setTypeface(fontsFamily.getNameFont(activity));

            holder.ViewPager_Images = (ViewPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pager);











            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (viewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }






        holder.questionName.setText(data.get(position).wallPost_Name);

        holder.commentDount.setText(spanString.changeStringSpanWall(data.get(position).wallPost_Images_Data
                .get(0).qst_Wall_Image_CommentCount + "", "Comments",activity));

        holder.okayCount.setText(spanString.changeStringSpanWall(data.get(position).wallPost_Images_Data
                .get(0).qst_Wall_Image_LikeCount + "", "Okay!",activity));

        holder.date.setText(fontsFamily.convertDate(data.get(position).wallPost_Date.toString(), activity));

        holder.userName.setText(data.get(position).wallPost_User_Name);

        //if(isScrolling==false)
        //imageLoader.DisplayImage(data.get(position).wallPost_User_Image, holder.userImage);



        final Vector<View> pages = new Vector<View>();
        //ViewPager
        /*CustomPagerAdapterForWall adap = new CustomPagerAdapterForWall(activity, activity, pages, data.get(position).wallPost_Images_Data);
        holder.ViewPager_Images.setAdapter(adap);
        holder.ViewPager_Images.setCurrentItem(pagePositon[position]);*/



        return convertView;
    }


    public class viewHolder
    {
        public  ViewPager ViewPager_Images ;
        public TextView questionName;
        public TextView userName;
        public TextView date;
        public TextView commentDount;
        public TextView okayCount;
        public ImageView userImage;
    }

}
```

Comment: I it struck without images also it give me the shock please give me some solution

Comment: show your java code  ,
I would suggest you use universal image loader for displaying images from net into a listview here is a sample code you can check out https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Please check my code but withouimages it is also struck

Comment: have you checked this code ?